# Google Android Maps directions

Tags: java, android-studio, google-maps

Estoy en un proyecto, donde tengo que crear una ruta con varios waypoints, me esta funcionando la url que mando y me devuelve la ruta. Pero no me funciona el optimizeWaypoints .

Esta es la URL =>

[https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=-34.704186,-58.290736&destination=-34.57572937011719,-58.424072265625&waypoints=-34.664146423339844,-58.379207611083984|-34.577518463134766,-58.42258834838867|-34.57329559326172,-58.419254302978516|-34.57769012451172,-58.42914962768555|-34.57416915893555,-58.43276596069336|-34.57769012451172,-58.42454528808594|-34.57582473754883,-58.434322357177734&sensor=true&mode=DRIVING&optimizeWaypoints=true&key=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX](https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=-34.704186,-58.290736&destination=-34.57572937011719,-58.424072265625&waypoints=-34.664146423339844,-58.379207611083984%7C-34.577518463134766,-58.42258834838867%7C-34.57329559326172,-58.419254302978516%7C-34.57769012451172,-58.42914962768555%7C-34.57416915893555,-58.43276596069336%7C-34.57769012451172,-58.42454528808594%7C-34.57582473754883,-58.434322357177734&sensor=true&mode=DRIVING&optimizeWaypoints=true&key=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX)

1. ¿Existe alguna librería para esto, para el cual no tenga que usar request? Ya que con JS es mucho mas fácil.
   Si no existe como realizaron esta petición

Comment: Estas usando algo nativo o estas usando una url, agrega màs informaciòn por favor. Estas requiriendo solo una opiniòn si existe una librerìa?

Comment: Pude encontrar una libreria, que aconseja google maps !